# String to DateTime conversion in PowerShell - French date

Tags: powershell, datetime

I can't convert my "french date". Any ideas ?

I can't find any solution... You can see an example of the date I need to convert to comment (#)

```
#          06.‎11.‎2016 ‏‎02:00
$format = "dd.‎MM.‎yyyy ‏‎HH:mm"
$provider = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture
$newDate = [datetime]::ParseExact($dateCreaString,$format,$provider)

Exception when calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "The string has not been recognized as a valid DateTime. »
+     $newDate = [datetime]::ParseExact($dateCreaString,$format,$provid ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException
```

Comment: `"dd.‎MM.‎yyyy ‏‎HH:mm"` contains zero-width unicode formatting characters, delete it and rewrite it by hand

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure I understand what you are looking for but if you are just looking to format the date you could use this...

```
$date=Get-Date -UFormat "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"
```

Comment: if you copy the text in the OP, and do this `"dd.‎MM.‎yyyy ‏‎HH:mm" | Format-Hex` you will see 4 different `?` characters embedded in the format string. it seems MathiasR.Jessen has pinpointed the problem. [*grin*]